# Update HTML table after insertion on db from another page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a simple web application with .net MVC. This application has two main pages (one for the operator and one for the client). The Client can insert rows in a table. The operator can read this table. Is there a way to show the table updated immediatly after the Client operation?  Now I reload the partial view with the table every 3000 ms but I would avoid it..

Comment: Consider [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: Did you take a look at `SignalR`? Jinx

Answer (score 0):

Once the page is rendered to the client you have only two ways of forcing a refresh. One is Javascript

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);", timeout);
```

The second is a Meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a new page which queries the last updated record in the table and . Then you can request this data with `ajax` on the Operator page withing a loop. If the record's ID (or you can use update date and time) got from the ajax is greater than the last record's ID that is already loaded then you can add a new row using JS or JQuery.